# Update statement changes wrong records

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

- I have a datagridview with 4 columns:  `UserID, FirstName, LastName, Email`
- When I double-click a row, another form pops up with 4 textboxes with the row's values inside those, each textbox with the cell value
- When I click the submit button, that row is updated with the textbox values.
- What I have works with `....where UserID = @UserID`.  But if a column cell 
  I'm changing IS the `UserId`, the wrong row, or no row, gets modified.

***Question***

How can I edit a row for ANY column value and it changes the right row WITHOUT an incrementer column?

***Code***

```
 public partial class EditUser : Form
{
    public DataGridViewRow dgvRow;
    public EditUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EditUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl5.Text = dgvRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtUserID.Text = dgvRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtFName.Text = dgvRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtLName.Text = dgvRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtEmail.Text = dgvRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        label1.Visible = false;
        txtUserID.Visible = false;
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        sc.ConnectionString = ("");
        sc.Open();
        com.Connection = sc;
        com.CommandText = ("update JoshUserTable SET UserID = @UserID, FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,Email=@Email where UserID = @UserID");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", txtUserID.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLName.Text);  
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);  
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
    }

    private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
        txtUserID.Visible = true;
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand con = new SqlCommand();
        sc.ConnectionString = ("");
        sc.Open();
        con.Connection = sc;
        con.CommandText = ("update JoshUserTable SET UserID = @UserID, FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,Email=@Email where FirstName = @FirstName");
        con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", txtUserID.Text);
        con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFName.Text);
        con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLName.Text);
        con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        con.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are running in a bigger problem at all. What if a record is changed by another user at the same time. You will run in a **concurrency problem**. That's why the auto generated code of a [CommandBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) always check for the old values.

For your current code I've added a check for the **original userID**.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    sc.ConnectionString = ("My Connection String");
    sc.Open();
    com.Connection = sc;

    /// check for original value in whereClause
    com.CommandText = ("update JoshUserTable SET UserID = @NEW_UserID,
                        FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,Email=@Email
                        where UserID = @ORIGINAL_UserID");


    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEW_UserID", txtUserID.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORIGINAL_UserID", INSERT_ORIGINAL_USERID);


    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFName.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLName.Text);  
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);  
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sc.Close();
}
```

The concurrency problem still stays unsolved....

Comment: Thanks for the input, I went a slightly different route.  Along with the userIDtext box, I made a label that shows the userID.  When the editform pops up, the UserIDtextbox is invisible.  Next to the UserID label, I have a linklabel "change" which if clicked, makes the UserID textbox visible with the intention of changing the name. If the link isn't checked, no intention of changing name. In my linkcheck event, I changed the where clause to match firstname and lastname, since chances are their name won't change even though the userID or e-mail might. However, the row doesn't change.. See above

Comment: Wow, It took me a second to figure out what wasn't making sense.  I was making my linklabel do way more than it's supposed to.

Comment: ok got you - anyway I really think you should **check for the original value(s) and set (a) new value(s)**. When calling `executeNonQuery()` you will get the number of updated records. If this record *is not equal 1* something went terribly wrong!

Comment: Furthermore If my answer was of any help for you, please consider voting it up and/or selecting it as the best answer.